# A single button that fires two self commands

Tags: python

I have two separate functions which were controlled by two buttons.

Button one:

```py
self.generate_negative_binomial_distribution_points = Button(self.init_window_name,
                                                         text="Generate",
                                                         command=self.generate_points)
```

Button two:

```py
self.str_trans_to_md5_button = Button(self.init_window_name,
                                      text="U Test",
                                      command=self.str_trans_to_md5)
```

Now I am trying to call the two commands in one button:

```py
self.figure_scatter_points = Button(self.init_window_name,
                                text="MC Sim",
                                command=lambda:(self.generate_points(), self.str_trans_to_md5()))
```

I was told "'Button' object is not callable".

Anyone can tell me how to change this code？

Thx in advance.

Comment: Can you post more of the code? The problem might be due to some naming conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what framework you are using, but lmabda should be used with functions. Your code should be something like this

```
self.figure_scatter_points = Button(self.init_window_name, text="MC Sim", command=lambda:(self.generate_points(), self.str_trans_to_md5()))
```

Comment: Thanks!I use Python. I tried your code, and was replied:  'Button' object is not callable

Comment: I understood that you are using tkinter. You need to know which part of your code is calling Button. Could you post your error traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wzl20\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\myprograms\pythonprogram\douban\distribution_test\Compare1.py", line 79, in <lambda>
    command=lambda:(self.generate_points(), self.str_trans_to_md5())) # 
TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable